# Next Prev Post link rendering current post thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails, next-post-link, previous-post-link

i am using below code which should render next and previous post thumbnail but it is showing the current post thumbnail in Custom Post Type single page

```
<?php 

$prevpost = get_previous_post(true);
$prevThumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevpost->ID, array(80,80) );

next_post_link('%link', '<span>' . $prevThumbnail . '</span>%title'); 

$nextpost = get_next_post(true);
$nextThumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextpost->ID, array(80,80) );

previous_post_link('%link', '<span>' . $nextThumbnail . '</span>%title');           

?>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: What [Wordpress Debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) Says ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without passing the `true` argument to [`get_previous_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post) function, because that paramters is used to get link of previous post of **same category**. Possibly you've not registered the `category` taxonomy while registering that custom post type.